# Image classification using CNN and Implementing it using API on the website

Tags: image, conv-neural-network, classification, object-detection, image-segmentation

As part of my project, I need to classify the images of a property website using API . The images of the website needs to be automatically tagged, and low quality images needs to be dropped. Also, sample images needs to be generated based on the product description. Can you please help me regarding this?

I tried out figuring what all APIs are available on market. The newly released Segment Anything API by Meta looked promising . But I am not able to figure out how to implement the Segment Anything API on the property website